# Need to SSO to a vendor using SAML, not sure what path to take

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs

I'm trying to set up a single-sign-on solution to a 3rd party site. They currently don't have anything set up on their end yet, but they want to use SAML. They instructed us to "provide them a sample of a standard SAML2.0 message", and sent over a certificate. Kind of asking me to show them a key and they'll build a lock to put it in.

I need some direction on what to actually set up for this. The vendor has cryptically stated that they are using these parts of the SAML message: ds:Signature, saml:Conditions, samlNameId. I've put together a C# console app that can produce a Saml2SecurityToken using their certificate and a given Name Identifier, and set a timeframe for the condition. I think this is what they need from me.

We do have ADFS however. I've used it to authenticate users accessing internal sites, so I have a little experience with it. I'm overwhelmed by the information for ADFS though, and can't grasp what to set up for this kind of situation - I don't know how to translate the vendor & I's relationship into ADFS terminology.

Can someone explain who I am and who they are in ADFS terms? I think all the pieces for setting this relationship are right there, but I'm just getting swamped by the volumes of information on every page about ADFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your ADFS site, navigate to:

```
https://your server/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml.
```

Save this file, send to the vendor. This is the metadata. It describes the SAML profiles, the certificates, the public keys etc. You don't need to send them any actual certificates.

Ask the vendor for their metadata. Import this into ADFS as a Claims Provider Trust.

Configure your application via WIF to use ADFS.

When the user navigates to the application, the user will be redirected to ADFS. They will get the Home Realm Discovery screen and select either the 3rd party vendor or ADFS to authenticate and then they will get access to the application.

If ADFS is the source of authentication ADFS is the IP, the vendor is the service provider (RP). And obviously vice versa.